# Python get foreground application name in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: python3

Currently, I am using Python 3 on Ubuntu 19.10. I have tried installing `wnck` and have failed.

I'm working on a gesture based project where I want to assign to the same gesture different commands for different applications. Is there any way to get only the application name and NOT the window title, since it changes for the same app (e.g. Chrome).

Below is a code I found online which helps extract the window title. I'd like to use the same code, but print the application name rather than the window title. Thank you.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import re

def get_active_window_title():
    root = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '-root', '_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = root.communicate()
    m = re.search(b'^_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.* ([\w]+)$', stdout)
    if m != None:
        window_id = m.group(1)
        window = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '-id', window_id, 'WM_NAME'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = window.communicate()
    else:
        return None

    match = re.match(b"WM_NAME\(\w+\) = (?P<name>.+)$", stdout)
    if match != None:
        return match.group("name").strip(b'"')

    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        while True:
            print(get_active_window_title())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change two lines:

- Change

  ```
  window = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '-id', window_id, 'WM_NAME'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  ```

  to

  ```
  window = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '-id', window_id, 'WM_CLASS'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  ```
- Change

  ```
  match = re.match(b"WM_NAME\(\w+\) = (?P<name>.+)$", stdout)
  ```

  to

  ```
  match = re.match(b'WM_CLASS\(\w+\) = ".*", (?P<name>.+)$', stdout)
  ```

Comment: Hey, your answer was very helpful since I'm using this code in my project. The issue I face right now after making the changes that you've told me are that when no window is selected or on desktop I get the following error : "xprop: error: Invalid window id format: 0x0." which I understand. What this does is that it breaks my code in which I import this. I'm unable to catch it with try except. Is there any way to get simple text or number in return when this occurs? I'm unable to compare the error with the same text which is what I need to do in my main code so text would be better. Help.

Comment: HI! I'm glad that this answer helped you! Please take a look [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156660), where someone had a problem similar to yours.